# Cannot check if point is on polyline. Islocationonedge function does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have a route and a point that's on the route. However, When I use the islocationonedge function to check, it doesn't work. I've adjusted the tolerance level but that doesn't solve the problem. I know this point is on the route but why isn't islocationonedge function confirming this? What am I doing wrong here?

```
 var addresses = [
  [
    [43.674687, -79.430955],
    [43.668560, -79.394924]
  ],
  [
    [43.674934, -79.426182],
    [43.675452, -79.423602]
  ],
  [
    [43.640381, -79.394508],
    [43.640575, -79.394586]
  ]
];


 var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {
        lat: 41.85,
        lng: -87.65
      }
    });
    
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(43.674687, -79.430955); 
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(43.668560, -79.394924); 

    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: "DRIVING"
      },
      function(response, status) {
        if (status === "OK") {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      var paths = response.routes[0].overview_path;
          var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: paths
          });

         if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(new google.maps.LatLng(addresses[1][1]), polyline, 1e-3)) {
    alert("Working");
  } else {
      alert("not working");
  }
                    
        } else {
          window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
        }
 
      }
       
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isLocationOnEdge function takes 2 or 3 arguments, per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.isLocationOnEdge):

> **isLocationOnEdge(point, poly[, tolerance])**
> **Parameters:**
> **point:**  LatLng
> **poly:**  Polygon|Polyline
> **tolerance:**  number optional
> **Return Value:**  boolean
> Computes whether the given point lies on or near to a polyline, or the edge of a polygon, within a specified tolerance. Returns true when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance. The tolerance defaults to 10-9 degrees.

The `point` argument must be a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng)

`addresses[1][1]` is an array of numbers.  The `google.maps.LatLng` constructor takes two numbers, not an array of two numbers. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng):

> **Constructor LatLng**
> **LatLng(lat, lng[, noWrap])**
> **Parameters:**
> **lat:**  number
> **lng:**  number
> **noWrap:**  boolean optional
> Creates a LatLng object representing a geographic point. Latitude is specified in degrees within the range [-90, 90]. Longitude is specified in degrees within the range [-180, 180]. Set noWrap to true to enable values outside of this range. Note the ordering of latitude and longitude.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8y6awfp0/)

[image: screenshot of map]

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

function initMap() {
  var addresses = [
    [
      [43.674687, -79.430955],
      [43.668560, -79.394924]
    ],
    [
      [43.674934, -79.426182],
      [43.675452, -79.423602]
    ],
    [
      [43.640381, -79.394508],
      [43.640575, -79.394586]
    ]
  ];


  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(43.674687, -79.430955);
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(43.668560, -79.394924);

  directionsService.route({
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: "DRIVING"
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === "OK") {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        var paths = response.routes[0].overview_path;
        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: paths,
          map: map
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(addresses[1][1][0], addresses[1][1][1]),
          map: map,
          title: "1",
          icon: {
            url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
          }
        })
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(new google.maps.LatLng(addresses[1][1][0], addresses[1][1][1]), polyline, 1e-3)) {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Working";
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "not working";
        }

      } else {
        window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
      }

    }

  );
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```